# Display part of the wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

i need to display main menu in footer inside 6 columns.
i don't want to add menu as HTML, i want it to be dynamic

I'm thinking to display part of the menu in each column. so one menu but displayed as parts.

Ex:

- Level 1

  - Level 2
  - Level 2

    - Level 2
- Level 1

  - Level 2
  - Level 2
- Level 1

  - Level 2
  - Level 2
  - Level 2
  - Level 2

now i want to display first menu items like ;

- Level 1

  - Level 2
  - Level 2

    - Level 2

in first column

then

- Level 1

  - Level 2
  - Level 2

in next (second) column

so on...

how do i do it in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy `wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );`   and paste to footer.php 
Reference : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: Thank you friend for the reply, i was actually looking to display only a part of the menu.